# Como faço pra retirar acentos e substituir espaços por: _?

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu tenho esse cara:

```
this.logger.logButton(`${this.selectedRadio.title}_${this.selectedRadio.cidade}`, { pram: 'paramValue' });
```

o retorno dele vem por exemplo: `Rádio Mix_São Paulo`
eu gostaria que o retorno fosse: `Radio_Mix_Sao_Paulo`

Como faço isso em angular/typescript?

Comment: Esse pode lhe ajudar sobre a retirada de pontuação. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript.         

Na parte do espaco vc pode pegar a variavel e fazer um `replace`. `_variavel.replace(' ', '_')`.

Answer (score 4):

Use o método replace passando expressões regulares

```js
const palavra = 'Rádio Mix_São Paulo';

const semEspacos = palavra.replace(/ /g, '_');
console.log(semEspacos);

const semAcentos = semEspacos.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '')
console.log(semAcentos);
```

O mais complicado de se entender aqui é provavelmente a parte de remover acentos. Primeiro o método `normalize` converte a string, transformando caracteres com acentos em dois caracteres separados, a letra e o acento. Depois a expressão regular converte todos os caracteres entre o código 300 e 36f do formato UTF-8 (o que inclui os acentos) em uma string vazia.